# Minimal, Reproducible Example - mention [in|out]put data

Tags: discussion, help-center, minimal-reproducible-example

I like the [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) page and often link to it when downvoting or closing a question.

What this page does not mention (and I think it should) is that it is very useful to also have some input (in code; short and simple) and the desired output posted.

I usually test my code before posting it on Stack Overflow and I find it frustrating when I have to come up with input data myself (or parse it first from the obscure format that was posted in the question) - and if there is no desired output I am not even entirely sure if that is what the OP wanted.

My suggestion would be to mention that input (as code) and the desired output should be provided on the [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) page.

Comment: *tell other readers what the expected behavior should be* sounds good to me, as do the multiple suggestions for what to do with code in the Complete section

Comment: Can't we have something like github gists? where multiple files can be made so it's easier to download it/seperate in relevant files and patch it in a project?

Comment: @CertainPerformance  "i have a list of lists where the second entry in the nested list is a string. i expect the  list to be sorted according to that second entry in the sublists". while this would satisfy the requirement you cite (i think) i'd find it very annoying to have to create test-data myself.

Comment: I can't help thinking that if the required test-data is so complex it's difficult to create you're probably not looking at a problem that has been reduced to its most minimal version. I'm sure there are exceptions but I feel that in general a *"minimal"* problem should have pretty simple input/output data.

Comment: @Tschallacka I think it's also reasonable to expect a minimal and representative dataset to be provided by OP. We can extrapolate it, if needed or OP can provide more, too. But we should at least have a starting point. I've also seen some questions where the OP lists a sample dataset in the question and links to a larger one (say, at least few megabytes) - that's an *option* but I don't think it's a requirement.

Comment: @ivarni even a "simple" input format, say, integers might be complex to come up with by us, the answerers. Very often I see a question that says "here is the code I tried and it doesn't work" or something to that effect. It might expect a list of numbers but `1, 2, 3` is not enough to trigger the problem - is it if you have repeat numbers? Numbers in non-ascending order? *Strings* instead of numbers? A certain amount of items in the list? Maybe it's the presence of the number `5` that triggers the issue. It's still worth giving the expected input.

Comment: @VLAZ Right, I wasn't considering a code dump like "here it is but it doesn't work" as an MRE in the first place but maybe that's the core of the issue here, that the MRE page doesn't point that out clearly enough.

Comment: @ivarni And then there are the questions that deal with *text input*, rather than numerical data... Asking for sample data is something I have to do with about 50% of the questions I see in the ms-word tag...